# Shadow Removing

Tags: rendering, shadows

I am trying to remove shadow from just one certain object through material properties >  settings > shadow mode from Opaque >> None, but the object is still casting a shadow. How can I remove the shadow being casted?

The object is a plane with a png image casted onto it

Comment: ++ I am using Cylces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cycles, remove *"shadow"* from the ray visibility:

[image]